# Installation of GDAL on MacOS Catalina is failing

Tags: python, django, macos, gdal, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install GDAL on my mac (Catalina 10.15.7) using brew:

```
brew install gdal
```

but I'm running into an error that I don't understand:

```
==> Pouring glib-2.66.4.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/glib/.: Operation not permitted
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/glib/.: Operation not permitted
Error: Failure while executing; `cp -pR /var/folders/7f/r7941wjd1fj2zlm79hwzlkcc0000gn/T/d20201223-26491-1643kjj/glib/. /usr/local/Cellar/glib` exited with 1. Here's the output:
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/glib/.: Operation not permitted
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/glib/.: Operation not permitted

Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Patching
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/<my_username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/54f3f612bdfc9bfc09633176c7673816fe2a2188e470bf48d60d826bdf6bf21a--hardcoded-paths.diff
```

I've also tried the following:

```
brew install --build-from-source gdal
```

But I run into the exact same error.
I don't really understand what's the problem, though it seems to be related to permissions.

I need some help on what I should do to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The following command:

```
  sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

and a reinstall, solved the problem.